# How can I let my function crash?

Tags: java

In certain cases I want my function to simply crash and my app to stop execution:

```
public void foo() {
    if(lifeIsWorthLiving) {
        /*code ...*/
    }
    else {
        /* log the problem, throw an exception and die */ 
    }
}
```

Now if I add `throw Exception("lifeIsWorthLiving = false !!!");` then I need to add `throws Exception` to function definition and then I have to handle this everywhere I call `foo()`. I don't want to do that. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Throw an [`RuntimeException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) or maybe [`Error`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html), depending on the nature of the problem. Both doesn't need to be declared in a `throws`. Last alternative is to call [`System#exit()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29).

Answer (score 6):

You can throw a [`RuntimeException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) or subclass thereof, which are unchecked. As per [the JLS §11.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/exceptions.html#44119):

> #### 11.2 Compile-Time Checking of Exceptions
>
> A compiler for the Java programming language checks, at compile time, that a program contains handlers for *checked exceptions*, by analyzing which checked exceptions can result from execution of a method or constructor. For each checked exception which is a possible result, the `throws` clause for the method or constructor must mention the class of that exception or one of the superclasses of the class of that exception.
> ...
> The *unchecked exceptions classes* are the class `RuntimeException` and its subclasses, and the class `Error` and its subclasses. All other exception classes are checked exception classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
throw new RuntimeException("lifeIsWorthLiving = false !!!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could throw a `RuntimeException` like others suggest, or better yet, throw an [Error](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) - the advantage being an `Error` won't be accidentally caught and handled by a `catch` block handling any kind of `Exception` farther up. This is assuming you're okay with "killing" your program with a `Throwable`, rather than closing it normally.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a [RuntimeException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). You will not need to handle it anywhere if you dont wish to.

Answer (score 0):

you could add `throw Exception("lifeIsWorthLiving = false !!!");` in try catch block

or just

```
void foo(){
        throw new Error(); // in place of exception
    }
```